# Can Scanner input in Java have a timeout?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Is it possible to override the scanner input (System.in), if the user doesn´t type anything in a defined time period like 5 sec.?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26172324/how-to-check-scanner-hasnextsystem-in-with-a-timeout-if-nothing-is-typed

Once you approach the problem as a timeout on input a few other questions turn up right away. HTH

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059068/set-timeout-for-users-input -
 much hacking involved

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853989/time-limit-for-an-input